# How to use `\multicolumn` in a table with borders defined in \begin{tabular}?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to create a Table like the one below:

[image: Desired Table]

I thought the following code would produce such a table, but I get an error, and I can't figure out why:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
 1 & 2  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Text}
 A & B
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any suggestions? I would like to avoid using a `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}` for each cell.

Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a `\\\` in the end of the line: `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Text}` ... Make it like this:
`\multicolumn{2}{l}{Text}\\\`

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! You have made some basic mistakes. You need to end each row with `\\ `. You may go through [this wikibook chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) to learn the basics of latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
 1 & 2  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Text}\\\hline
 A & B\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```